# d3 : Y Axis intervals not getting set by ticks

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, d3.js

I want to set Y Axis by 0-100 percent in the intervals of `0-25-50-75-100`.

For that I am setting ticks to 4.

But I can see Y axis in the intervals of `0-20-40-60-80-100`

**How can I set Y axis in the intervals of 0-25-50-75-100 ??**

I have below code -

```
  const extent=[0,100];
  const yScale = scaleLinear().domain(extent).range([height, 0]);
  
  const x0Scale = scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map((d) => d.month))
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(0.46);
  const x1Scale = scaleBand()
   // .domain(data.map((d) => d.type))
    .rangeRound([0, x0Scale.bandwidth()])
    .padding(0.22);

  const xAix = axisBottom(x0Scale);
  const yAix = axisLeft(yScale);
  

  svg
  .select(".x-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${xMargin}, ${height + yMargin})`)
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("font-size", "0.700rem")
  .call(xAix);
  
  svg
    .select(".y-axis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${0 + xMargin}, ${yMargin} )`)   
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("font-size", "0.725rem")      
    .call(yAix.ticks(4).tickSize(-width).tickFormat(function(d){return d + "%"}));
```

Comment: d3 takes priority for some of the tick functions , you can do force tick Values by tickValues(d3.range(minValue, maxValue, 4)); . In your case  yAix.tickSize(-width).tickValues(d3.range(0,100,4).tickFormat...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

d3 takes priority for some of the tick functions , you can do force tick Values by tickValues(d3.range(minValue, maxValue, noOfSteps)); . In your case

**yAix.tickSize(-width).tickValues(d3.range(0,100,4).tickFormat(function(d){return d + "%"})**

or use tickValues(d3.range(d3.min(dataarray),d3.max(dataarray),noOfticks))

Answer (score 2):

Use `tickValues` instead of `ticks`.

```
svg
  .select(".y-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${0 + xMargin}, ${yMargin} )`)   
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("font-size", "0.725rem")      
  .call(yAix
    .ticksValues([0, 25, 50, 75, 100])
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickFormat(function(d){return d + "%"}));
```

`ticks` is used as a hint only - d3 might display a few more or less ticks, depending on the scale and the available screen space.

`tickValues` allows you to select the exact values for which to display ticks.